# ESP32 Issues with receiving 433Mhz when the WiFi library is used

Tags: arduino-esp32

I want to use a ESP32 to receive signals from 433Mhz, take that message and place on a MQTT topic.

The circuit is simple.  I have a ESP32 WROOM and connected to GPIO35 is a QAM_RX 433Mhz receiver

The idea is to have a interrupt function that is called every time on a state change.  I.e. rising or falling edge.  The function then measures the microseconds between the state changes and records the length of the pulse and its state.

Of course the function first looks for a preample before recording and likewise a postample to stop.

I "had" this all working. I was receiving 433Mhz messages and displaying the data to the Serial port.

Example code is below.

```
#define RAWBITBUFFERSIZE 150

typedef struct {
  bool state;                   // state 0 or 1 (Boolean)
  uint32_t duration;            // duration of the state in ms
} PULSE;

PULSE rawBitBuffer[RAWBITBUFFERSIZE];
uint32_t rawBitBufferPosition;
bool isMessageReceived = false;

void IRAM_ATTR handleInterrupt() {
  static uint32_t lastTime = 0;
  uint32_t now = micros();
  uint32_t duration = now - lastTime;
  lastTime = now;

  static bool preambleDetected = false;
  static bool postambleDetected = false;
  static bool lastState = false;

  bool state = digitalRead(35);

  if (!preambleDetected) {
    if (state == HIGH && duration >= 4000 && duration <= 12500) {
      // Preamble detected
      preambleDetected = true;
      rawBitBufferPosition = 0;
      lastState = state;
      return;
    }
  } else {
    if (state != lastState) {
      rawBitBuffer[rawBitBufferPosition].state = lastState;
      rawBitBuffer[rawBitBufferPosition].duration = duration;
      rawBitBufferPosition++;

      if (rawBitBufferPosition >= RAWBITBUFFERSIZE) {
        // Buffer overflow, reset and start over
        rawBitBufferPosition = 0;
        preambleDetected = false;
        postambleDetected = false;
        return;
      }

      if (state == LOW && duration >= 4000 && duration <= 12500) {
        // Postamble detected, message complete
        postambleDetected = true;
        isMessageReceived = true;
        return;
      }

      lastState = state;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(35, INPUT);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(35), handleInterrupt, CHANGE);

  // other setup code for WiFi and MQTT
}

void loop() {
  // other loop code for WiFi and MQTT

  if (isMessageReceived) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rawBitBufferPosition; i++) {
      Serial.print("x = ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(", S = ");
      Serial.print(rawBitBuffer[i].state);
      Serial.print(", D = ");
      Serial.println(rawBitBuffer[i].duration);
    }

    // reset flags and buffer position
    isMessageReceived = false;
    rawBitBufferPosition = 0;
  }
}
```

My problems start when I add the WiFi code.

I either receive no message, sometimes I get message, or sometimes I receive garbage.

My WiFi additions look like

```
#include <WiFi.h>

#define RAWBITBUFFERSIZE 150

typedef struct {
  bool state;                       // state 0 or 1 (Boolean)
  uint32_t duration;            // duration of the state in ms
} PULSE;

PULSE rawBitBuffer[RAWBITBUFFERSIZE];
uint32_t rawBitBufferPosition;
bool isMessageReceived = false;

void IRAM_ATTR handleInterrupt() {
  static uint32_t lastTime = 0;
  uint32_t now = micros();
  uint32_t duration = now - lastTime;
  lastTime = now;

  static bool preambleDetected = false;
  static bool postambleDetected = false;
  static bool lastState = false;

  bool state = digitalRead(35);

  if (!preambleDetected) {
    if (state == HIGH && duration >= 4000 && duration <= 12500) {
      // Preamble detected
      preambleDetected = true;
      rawBitBufferPosition = 0;
      lastState = state;
      return;
    }
  } else {
    if (state != lastState) {
      rawBitBuffer[rawBitBufferPosition].state = lastState;
      rawBitBuffer[rawBitBufferPosition].duration = duration;
      rawBitBufferPosition++;

      if (rawBitBufferPosition >= RAWBITBUFFERSIZE) {
        // Buffer overflow, reset and start over
        rawBitBufferPosition = 0;
        preambleDetected = false;
        postambleDetected = false;
        return;
      }

      if (state == LOW && duration >= 4000 && duration <= 12500) {
        // Postamble detected, message complete
        postambleDetected = true;
        isMessageReceived = true;
        return;
      }

      lastState = state;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(35, INPUT);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(35), handleInterrupt, CHANGE);

  // other setup code for WiFi
  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  delay(1000);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  WiFi.begin("myssid", "mypassword");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(WiFi.status());
  }
}

void loop() {
  // other loop code for WiFi and MQTT

  if (isMessageReceived) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rawBitBufferPosition; i++) {
      Serial.print("x = ");
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(", S = ");
      Serial.print(rawBitBuffer[i].state);
      Serial.print(", D = ");
      Serial.println(rawBitBuffer[i].duration);
    }

    // reset flags and buffer position
    isMessageReceived = false;
    rawBitBufferPosition = 0;
  }
}
```

my platformio.ini file looks like this

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
```

I checked the ESP32 pinout and I don't appear to be using any GPIO pins the WiFi would use.

I'm guessing with WiFi enabled my 433 Interrupt isn't getting called quick enough to record the correct duration times between the state changes.

I tried turning the WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF) when I detected a preample and then at the postample doing a WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA) and WiFi.begin(....) but its not good enough if I'm receiving lots of data and need to connect to a MQTT broker.

What am I doing wrong? or should do differently?

Comment: Accordingly with my experience with ESP32S3 when you start running a heavy stack like the WiFi or LVGL etc you easily gonna loose data if you try to your code on an Interrrupt or while 1 loop such as Serial Port reading.
My strong advice is to start a Thread and handle it from there like:

xTaskCreate(th_handleInterrupt, "handleInterrupt", 1024, NULL, 5, &h_handleInterrupt);

Write your own thread function and work from there....

I hope it helped